# Node.js Fedora and OpenSSL

Tags: node.js, openssl, fedora

For some reason it seems that the ./configure option of the node.js package doesn't see that I have openSSL already installed (via yum) on fedora.

What do I have to do to get openssl support for node with fedora?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I​n​s​t​a​l​l `openssl-devel`.